# Serial Communication with two bluetooth modules on Arduino Mega

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, bluetooth

I'm trying to communicate with two bluetooth module (RN-42) on the Arduino Mega.

I studied about Serial communication in Arduino, and I used Serial1, Serial2 to get information at the same time from the modules.

At the setup period, baud rate will be set. The command "$$$" makes the bluetooth module go into the configuration mode. Until this, everything works pretty well.

The problem is, it seems nothing works inside the loop(). I think Serial1.print(inByte), Serial2.print(inByte) doesn't work properly. I checked the TX1, TX2 port whether it sends any data or not by using LED, and the LED never blinked.

Here's the code that I used.

```cpp
void setup() {
  // initialize both serial ports:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial1.begin(115200);
  Serial1.print("$$$");
  delay(100);
  Serial1.println("U,9600,N");
  Serial1.begin(9600);

  delay(100);
  Serial1.print("?");

  Serial2.begin(115200);
  Serial2.print("$$$");
  delay(100);
  Serial2.println("U,9600,N");
  Serial2.begin(9600);


}

void loop() {
  // read from port 1, send to port 0:

  while(Serial1.available()>0) {
    char inByte = Serial1.read();
    Serial.print(inByte); 
  }


  while(Serial2.available()>0) {
    char inByte = Serial2.read();
    Serial.print(inByte);
  }


  // read from port 0, send to port 1:
  while (Serial.available()>0) {
    char inByte = Serial.read();
    Serial1.print(inByte);

    delay(10);
    Serial2.print(inByte);   
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Maybe try a Serial1.end() before the second Serial1.begin? Arduino reference documentation gives no specific info here. How do you exit command mode?

Comment: What i dont see is the part where you are asking module 1 to act as master, module2 to act as slave. And ask module 1 to connect to module 2.